# How do I refactor this hook call to avoid Invalid Hook error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

How do i refactor this code so I can still push each item into the list while passing in the current state of both isGood and isSubGood?

Looks like the code that causes the issue is when I try to push each assessmentData into listItems

```
  export default function AssessmentsGraphData(props) {
    const [createModal, setCreateModal] = React.useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = React.useState(false);
    const [isGood, setIsGood] = React.useState(false);
    const [isSubGood, setIsSubGood] = React.useState(false);

    const graphData = props.data;
    const isUserAllowedEdit = props.isUserAllowedEdit;
    const userId = props.userId;
    let results;
    let listItems = [];

    useEffect(() => {
        if (graphData) {
            graphData.forEach((assessmentData) => {
                    if (assessmentData.assessmentType === 'HERE') {
                        setIsGood(true);
                    }
                    if (
                        assessmentData.assessmentType === 'THAT' ||
                        assessmentData.assessmentType === 'THIS' ||
                        assessmentData.assessmentType === 'OTHER'
                    ) {
                        setIsGoog(true);
                        setIsSubGood(true);
                    }

                    console.log("added item: " + assessmentData)
                     listItems.push(
                                Assessment.individualAssessment(
                                    assessmentData,
                                    userId,
                                    isGood,
                                    isSubGood,
                                    isUserAllowedEdit,
                                    props.handleUpdateSuccess,
                                )
                   );
                }
            )
        }
    },[]);







    results = (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Drilldown
                animateHeight
                aria-label="Results"
                data={{
                    panel: {
                        listHeader: 'Member',
                        listItems: listItems
                    }
                }}
            />
            <br />
            {!isGood ? (
                <Card>
                    <Card.Body>
                        <Headline>Create new for selected member</Headline>
                        <br />
                        <br />

                        <Modal open={createModal} onClose={setCreateModal} large>
                            <Modal.Body>
                                <CreatePvnAssessment
                                    isUserAllowedEdit={isUserAllowedEdit}
                                    memberPartyId={graphData.partyId}
                                    memberPartyIdType={graphData.partyIdType}
                                    userId={userId}
                                    handleUpdateSuccess={props.handleUpdateSuccess}
                                />
                            </Modal.Body>
                        </Modal>
                        <Modal open={error} onClose={setError} small>
                            <Modal.Body>
                                <Headline p={15}>Record failed to update</Headline>
                            </Modal.Body>
                        </Modal>
                        <Grid.Row>
                            <Grid.Column sm="6">
                                <Button onClick={() => setCreateModal(true)}>Create</Button>
                            </Grid.Column>
                        </Grid.Row>
                    </Card.Body>
                </Card>
            ) : (
                <></>
            )}
        </React.Fragment>
    );

    return <React.Fragment>{results}</React.Fragment>;
}
```

I have updated the question to include the entire functional component (left out the imports)

Comment: Hello! We need your whole component code.

Comment: The issue is still `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.` ?? Why don't you return results directly as it's already envolved with fragments?

Comment: yup. Still the same error. I tried returning results directly but still same issue

Comment: The line that causes the issue is  listItems.push(.... how can I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

I see no issue with your `useEffect` hook, but keep in mind that you always have to put it inside a **React Functional Component**. As you don't share the whole component I suppose that is the issue that you're having.

See [this](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) for further info.